# Guided Scrolling on web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How does this page accomplish the (guided scrolling?) technique between two divs, where with just a small flick on the scroll pad it takes you to the next element?

http://sourcing.alibaba.com/buyermarket/buyer_market_home.htm?tracelog=alihomelink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a library, I'd suggest [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). I used it in a recent project and it does the trick without even bother.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of methods to achieve this. One of them is [jQuery Mousewheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel).

Here is a simple example of how it works:

```
$('#my_elem').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
console.log(event.deltaX, event.deltaY, event.deltaFactor);
});

// using the event helper
$('#my_elem').mousewheel(function(event) {
console.log(event.deltaX, event.deltaY, event.deltaFactor);
});
```

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/DgmWs/5/

Answer (score 0):

Didn't check what library they are using as they are more than likely using a function in jquery or dojo to do this for them but in terms on pure js and dom intereaction. They are doing something like this

```
window.onscroll = function (oEvent) {
    // called when the window is scrolled.
    var el = document.getElementById('#someid');//could be selecting the element by class or other means
    el.scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

See the docs for more details:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollIntoView
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll